# Does memset change the array length when another array is memset?

Tags: c++, arrays, c-strings, memset

**program-1**->

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char a[4];
    memset(a, 'A', sizeof a);
    std::cout << a << '!';

    return 0;
}
```

program-1 outputs what I expected `AAAA!`
But as soon as I introduce another string (char array), things change!

**program-2**->

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char a[4], b[4];
    memset(a, 'A', sizeof a);
    memset(b, 'B', sizeof b);
    std::cout << a << '!';
    std::cout << ' ' << b << '?';

    return 0;
}
```

program-2 outputs `AAAABBBB! BBBB?`. That means, here `a` is `AAAABBBB`
But I declared the length as 4! So what is going on? Does memset change the array length when another array is `memset` or something?!

My build line is `g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 main.cpp -o main`

Comment: `std::cout` prints chars until `\0`. There's no such in your array, so it continues past `a`, which is UB

Comment: So if I want to fill a string with a character using memset properly (having a `\0` at the end), how to do that?

Comment: you need to allocate one more char for the null terminator '\0'. instead of 4 allocate 5. 
`char a[5], b[5];` and memset never change the array length.

Comment: @Adam what will be the memset line?

Comment: And don't pass the whole array size to memset, leave one character for zero.

Comment: simple. `memset(a, 'A', array_length -1);` or if you already assigned \0 to the last array element u can use `strlen()`. like so: `memset(a, 'A', strlen(a));`

Comment: Also, use `std::string` instead of character arrays in C++ unless you have a really good reason to use character arrays. (You almost certainly don't.) C spells "string" `char[]`. C++ spells string `std::string`.

Comment: @Adam what do u mean by `array_length`? Do u mean `sizeof a`? It still does not work

Comment: sizeof(a) is wrong to use (even if its work in some cases).

Comment: @Adam `strlen(a)` did not work either!

Answer (score 0):

> Does memset change the array length

No. Memset does not change the array length. In fact the length of any array never changes through the lifetime of the array.

> So what is going on?

The stream insertion operator that you use has the pre condition that the string must be null terminated. Violating pre conditions results in undefined behaviour.

You insert non-null terminated strings into the character stream. This violates the pre condition and the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Comment: I know u answered the mentioned questions, but could u provide a way by which I can memset an array and at the same time have a `\0` at the end!

Comment: You can use the assignment operator to set the value of a character.

Comment: Do you mean that, declaration and memset could stay the same and after memset, I should say `a[4] = '\0';`? Well, It does not work! Can u please elaborate?

Comment: Index 4 is outside the bounds of the array. Assigning to outside the bounds has undefined behaviour.

Comment: then  what do u suggest? Can u make it a little clearer than just an "assignment operator"?  Please instead of just saying what is wrong, could u add what will work?

Comment: Do what you suggested except using an index that is within the array.